# XML script in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services

It is possible to run xml script from Reporting Builder (generating using Report Model) in Management Studio? I only want to see result of this command.

[image]

Comment: are you trying to import it ?

Comment: No, just copy this output from Reporting Builder window.

Comment: try to import xml file, there are lot of MS documentations related to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done like below -

`<Query>
<XmlData>`

`here goes your XML content`

`</XmlData>
</Query>`

Though I would say your question is very much incomplete and to provide a correct solution you need to provide more details (like - what you want to do with the xml, how you are getting the xml, total xml content etc.) .

Comment: I get error that it works only with stored procedure.

Comment: http://imgur.com/MTCrdAd | I want to run this file in management studio to compare with result gained from Reporting Model

Comment: No you can't run a xml document in management studio (ssms). If you want to retrieve the values of the nodes/attributes then you need to parse the xml through TSQL statements. The way I have suggested will work only in reports.